# Adding extra image/icon to label using JFace Tree and Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, tree, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using a JFace TreeViewer object in my Eclipse RCP ViewPart, and I'd like to add some additional information to the label on some of my nodes by way of an image.

Essentially the image should sit to the right of the label text and will represent a rating (I'm thinking 1 - 5 stars)

If there's a way to do this I can't find it, does anybody know of one?

If not then does anyone know how the eclipse package explorer shows the different coloured extra info when using other plugins like Subclipse? I guess if I'm forced to I could use that and the "*" character? ( I have tried to look at the source but it's very abstracted and a little beyond me at the moment, so I'm just asking if anyone knows off hand, I'm not asking anyone to dig through the source for me)

Regards,

Glen

x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom-draw tree items by adding `SWT.MeasureItem` and `SWT.PaintItem`listeners to the tree. Check out example 5 in [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html).

In order to get the selection highlight painted over the extended area, add also `SWT.EraseItem` listener and update `event.width`.

Comment: Thanks, this is how I implemented it, however that link was already provided by aphex so I didn't give you the answer credit. Sorry.

Comment: Any idea how to make the selection box size encompass the extra image too?

Comment: Thanks that worked, for some reason my image background isn't transparent though so the highlight looks stupid. Working on that now. sigh.

Comment: Ok so that sort of works, but only if you hover over the label, I was hoping there's be a way to set it up so that the area that counts as being over the node extended out, so you could hover over the image to select it.

Comment: @GlenLamb SWT mouse events are not hooked up to native events like the painting functionality is. You'll just have to listen to mouse move and click events and do all those things "manually".

Comment: Sounds like too much effort, I'll leave the highlight off of the extra image I think, because SWT Images don't seem to allow me to draw my image on a transparent background anyway so when the highlight kicks in the background of the image just makes it look bad anyway.

Comment: @GlenLamb [SWT Image transparency](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do what I want, I build create a blank image and then draw 5 stars on to it next to each other, the stars are loaded from a file and have varies degrees of transparency so simply post processing my image cause artefacts where the semi alpha pixels from the original image have already blended with the white background. What I want is a way to create a new image that is properly transparent that I can draw my images on to, but there's just no way to do it with SWT it seems.

Comment: @Mark I'm sorry to drag this up again but you seem like an expert in this stuff and I'm lost, I've beenpicking down through Tree and Widget etc trying to find the piece of code that gets executed to check if a the mouse pointer is hovering over an entry, so that I can change the range of the nodes to encompass my second image.

I'm working on the basis that at some point them must be a piece of code that "asks" each node if they are being hovered over, and i'm searching for that code so that I can overide it somehow with my own

Comment: Is that the wrong approach? Should I just be looking to add listeners on top and "simulate" the hover event? these widgets seem to be very complex and I don't much care for the coding standards used. But then I guess they aren't for the likes of me to play with.

Comment: One strange thing I've noticed is that if the tree's width is smaller than the nodes width the behaviour I want is already there, is there someway to exploit that?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the PackageExplorer or your own TreeViewer ?

**1.PackageExplorer**: You need to extend the ui decorator.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
    <decorator
    adaptable="true"
    class="org.example.com.PackageExplorerDecorator"
    id="org.example.filedecorator"
    label="File Decorator"
    lightweight="true"
    state="true">
 <enablement>
    <or>
       <objectClass
             name="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod">
       </objectClass>
       <objectClass
             name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
       </objectClass>
    </or>
 </enablement>
```

The class should look like this:

```
public class PackageExplorerDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator {

    @Override
    public void decorate(final Object resource, final IDecoration decoration) {
       decoration.addSuffix(..)
       decoration.addPrefix(..)
    }
}
```

**2. TreeViewer:** You can try to create custom Widget, or just create TreeViewer with multiple columns ( First one for the tree and the second one for the stars).

[This](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) and [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet051TableCenteredImage.java?view=markup) might be for you useful.

Comment: I've tried to use multiple columns but as soon as I do all of my content disappears, I've tried providing the col with a label provider but that's not helping, the tree just looks empty but the strange thing is that selection is sort of working as I can right click for my context menus and left click and my property view is picking things up. It's most odd. Any thoughts?

Comment: you need to provide for every column an provider